# script not working when executed once

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I have the following code on my web page. SetDivPosition and window.onload is to mantain the scroll bar position on postback on div tag and $(document).ready 
function is when the user first visits this page than the scroll bar needs to be all the way to the bottom, this needs to be done only one time when user first
 got redirected to the page. If I first visit the page than the scroll bar is all the way to the top. I want it to be at the bottom and 
also mantain the scroll bar position on the postbacks. I can do only one thing at this time, I can either maintain the scroll bar position or 
move the scroll bar all the way to the bottom. Can I accomplish both the things.

any help will be greatly appreciated.

```
    <head runat="server">
    <title></title>
      <script src="Scripts/jquery-1.9.1.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

    <script src="Scripts/jquery.cookie.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type = "text/javascript">
        function SetDivPosition() {
            var intY = document.getElementById("scrollArea").scrollTop;
            document.cookie = "yPos=!~" + intY + "~!";
        }

        window.onload = function () {
            var strCook = document.cookie;
            if (strCook.indexOf("!~") != 0) {
                var intS = strCook.indexOf("!~");
                var intE = strCook.indexOf("~!");
                var strPos = strCook.substring(intS + 2, intE);
                document.getElementById("scrollArea").scrollTop = strPos;
            }
        }


        $(document).ready(function () {

            if ($.cookie("scriptExecuted") != "yes") {
                //Scroll div you the bottom onpage load
                $("#scrollArea").scrollTop($("#scrollArea")[0].scrollHeight);

                $.cookie("scriptExecuted", "yes");
            }
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div id="scrollArea" style="overflow-y: scroll; height: 260px; width: 300px" onscroll="javascript:SetDivPosition();">
      This is some text.<br />
        This is some text.<br />
        This is some text.<br />
        This is some text.<br />
        This is some text.<br />
        This is some text.<br />
        This is some text.<br />
        This is some text.<br />
        This is some text.<br />
        This is some text.<br />
        This is some text.<br />
        This is some text.<br />
        This is some text.<br />
        This is some text.<br />
        This is some text.<br />
        This is some text.<br />
        This is some text.<br />
        This is some text.<br />
        This is some text.<br />
        This is some text.<br />
        This is some text.<br />
        This is some text.<br />
        This is some text.<br />
        This is some text.<br />
        This is some text.<br />
        This is some text.<br />
        This is some text.<br />
        This is some text.<br />
        This is some text.<br />
        This is some text.<br />
        This is some text.<br />
        This is some text.<br />
        This is some text.<br />
        This is some text.<br />
        This is some text.<br />
        This is some text.<br />
        This is some text.<br />
        This is some text.<br />
        This is some text.<br />
        This is some text.<br />
        This is some text.<br />
        This is some text.<br />
        This is some text.<br />
        This is some text.<br />
        This is some text.<br />
        This is some text.<br />
        This is some text.<br />
        This is some text.<br />
        This is some text.<br />
        This is some text.<br />



    </div>
    <asp:Button Text="Submit" runat="server" />
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: since you are using `.net` call the function in `!isPostback` function of `ASP.net`

Comment: why can't I call it as javascript?

Comment: you can do it on javascript/jquery but in javascript/jquery there is no concept called as `postback` so you need to do something like this **In C#, it would look a bit like this:**

`ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(GetType(), 
         "isPostBack", 
         String.Format("var isPostback = {0};", IsPostBack.ToString().ToLower()),
         true);`

**JavaScript:**

`if(isPostback) {
     // Postback specific logic here
}`

Comment: but since .net provided native `!isPostback` its easier to implement your logic there... its like you wanna cross a river you can either swim or take a boat... since you have access to boat why sweat on swimming :)

Comment: @Anjali5 instead of  `$(document).ready(function () {}` keep the code that you want to call everytime in `function pageLoad(){}` in aspx page i.e. Javascript

Comment: I want to call window.onload everytime and document.ready only the first time and that is the reason, I used cookies. I am not sue what you are suggesting